# Insert URL path into database using dbplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr

I'm trying to insert a url into a postgresql database using

```
db_insert_into(con, "url", "http://www.google.com")
```

Error in file(fn, open = "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fn, open = "r") :
cannot open file 'http:/www.google.com': No such file or directory

How can I solve this?

Comment: Besides `dbplyr`, which packages are you using?

Comment: If `con` is a database connection, is`"url"` the *table name* or the *field name*? What happens if you instead do `db_insert_into(con, "tablename", data.frame(url="http://www.google.com", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`?

Comment: That worked perfect. Could you post your solution so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow specify both the table name and the field name. I'm going to guess that `"url"` is the field name, and the table name is as yet undefined here. But it doesn't matter, frankly, take the solution and adapt as needed.

The expectation of `db_insert_into` is that the `values` (third argument) is a `data.frame` or something that can easily be converted to such. So you can probably do:

```
newdata <- data.frame(url = "http://www.google.com", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
db_insert_into(con, "tablename", newdata)
```

If you're lazy or playing code-golf, you might be able to do it with:

```
db_insert_into(con, "tablename", list(url = "http://google.com"))
```

since some of the underlying S3 or S4 methods around `dbplyr` sometimes check `if (!is.data.frame(values)) values <- as.data.frame(values)`. (But I wouldn't necessarily rely on that, it's usually better to be explicit.)